# How to animate article border

Tags: jquery, html

I have simple article element `<article id="why-me" style="">text</article>` with style:

```
article {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border: 2px solid #353535;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

section#content article {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #050505;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

So i trying to do flash border like `jQuery('#why-me').animate({'borderColor': '#717171'});`, but nothing happens... Where is the problem?

Comment: Is jQuery ui included?

Comment: if you just want to change the color you can use `.css('border-color', '#717171')`, but to actually animate the color you'll have to use a plugin. There is an [official jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) and there's also [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color animation is not part of jQuery by default. You need a pluggin for that:

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Answer (score 0):

If jquery is included, you have to specify the duration of the animation:

```
jQuery('#why-me').animate({'borderColor': '#717171'},fast);
```

Comment: This answer is inaccurate and not quite correct. Please review it